# how to check the same ID in a different dataframe and make the merge file?

Tags: r

I want to modify the longitudinal data based on ID.
I want to check whether the IDs in data wave 1(A) and data in wave 2(B) match properly. Also, I want to combine the data of A and B into one file based on ID.

I tried to merge the file using merge() code and tried to check whether the ID matched through the sex variable. However, it is difficult to check ID if there is no same variable in both waves, and it does not directly check each ID.

```
ID <- c(1012,1102,1033,1204,1555)
sex <- c(1,0,1,0,1)
A <- cbind(ID,sex)
A <- as.data.frame(A)

ID <- c(1006,1102,1001,1033,1010,1234,1506,1999)
sex <- c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
B <- cbind(ID,sex)
B <- as.data.frame(B)

merge.AB<-merge(A,B,by="ID")
all(merge.AB$sex.x == merge.AB$sex.y)
```

**1. Are there any way to merge A(wave1) and B(wave2) files by ID other than `merge()` code?**

- Since there are 2 or 3 wave1 files other than A, it would be nice to be able to combine several files at once.

**2. Is there a way to check if two frames have the same ID directly?**

I tried to combine the files and check matching IDs through `cbind()` code for combining the A and B. But I couldn't check them together because the number of rows between the A and B dataframe is different.

- It would be helpful to use a loop(e.g. if, for, etc.), but it would be nice if there was a way to do it with a package or simple code.

**3. How do I locate a row number with a mismatched ID?**

- I want to know the all of locations in the row(row number) for the example.

e.g.
mismatched ID in A: 1012,1204,1555

mismatched ID in B: 1006,1001,1010,1234,1506,1999

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1** : you can merge multiple dataframes with `merge`. You first need to create a list of the df you want to merge and then you could use `Reduce`.

```
df_list <- list(df1,df2,...dfn)
data=Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x=x,y=y,by="ID",all=T),df_list)
```

Alternatively using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_list %>% reduce(full_join, by='ID')
```

In your example, pay attention that it is not convenient to merge two df with the same variable name and that contain the same information. You could simply use

```
data=Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x=x,y=y,all=T), df_list)
```

to remove redundant information from merged df.

**Question 2** : check IDs with `setdiff()` and `intersect()`

`intersect()` gives you the common values between two vectors
`setdiff(x,y)` gives you the values in `x` that are not present in `y`

```
intersect(A$ID,B$ID)
[1] 1102 1033

setdiff(A$ID,B$ID)
[1] 1012 1204 1555

setdiff(B$ID,A$ID)
[1] 1006 1001 1010 1234 1506 1999
```

**Question 3** : a simple `which()` including `%in%` test will give you the position in the dataframe

```
which(!(A$ID %in% B$ID))
[1] 1 4 5
which(!(B$ID %in% A$ID))
[1] 1 3 5 6 7 8
```